# RandomBeans throws IllegalArgumentException("Primitive types can't be instantiated in Java")

Tags: java, random-beans

I want to create ["randombeans"](https://github.com/benas/random-beans) of a veriy simple class:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FileData {
    @NonNull
    private String fileName;
    @NonNull
    private LocalDateTime uploadTime;
    @NonNull
    private Boolean read = false;
    @NonNull
    private String path;
}
```

(for those not familiar with Lombok: those annotations generate getter and setter (with nullcheck here) for each field. Additionally 2 constructors are added.)

I am trying to creaate a rondom list of instances with:

```
EnhancedRandom.randomListOf( 10, FileData.class );
```

But this isn't working:

`IllegalArgumentException("Primitive types can't be instantiated in Java")`

The docu say primitive types should work?! So what is wrong here? How to work around this?

Comment: Try to make `private Boolean read = new Boolean(false);`

Comment: this didn't helped